# Unable to use http.post in compute() function

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use the compute() function to trigger a top level method that calls an HTTP POST.

I can see the method being executed, but then it just hangs where I do the actual post, with no errors returned.

However if I call this without calling compute, it works fine

```
uploadData(Map args) {
  print("uploading data"); // i see this in the logs

  API().uploadData(args["data"], args["user"], args["apikey"]);
}
```

and it's called via

```
 compute(uploadData, {
        "data": dataList,
        "user": widget.userProps,
        "apikey": widget.apiKey
      });
```

lastly this is my API uploadData method

```
  uploadData(List files, User userdata, String apikey) async {
    try {
      String sessionid = await _getSession();
      String _base = 'http://192.168.2.13:3000/upload';
      String body = json.encode({
        "api": apikey,
        "user": userdata.toMap(),
        "data": files,
        "sessionid": sessionid
      });
      print("I AM HERE"); // this is called
      await http.post(_base,
          body: body, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
     print("this is not called");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error"); // no error
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What happens when you call that function?

Comment: If I call uploadData on its own, it works fine, if I call uploadData inside compute() it executes up to where it says "I AM HERE" and then stalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to `return`, because `API().uploadData` returns a future (of null, I assume). If we don't return, `API().uploadData` is executed and then `uploadData(Map args)` return `null` value and pops out of the stack immediate; isolate has no functions, microtask queue or event queue left, it will exit.

```dart
uploadData(Map args) {
  print("uploading data"); // i see this in the logs

  return API().uploadData(args["data"], args["user"], args["apikey"]);
}
```